Plotting an aging SSP using for loops
I have a bunch of FITS files for different star types which each have flux and wavelength column. I have found their main-sequence lifetimes and their weighted ratio of each spectral class with respect to mass to the total sample. I have also found the total weighted flux for each of the stars greater than said timestep. I am now trying to plot the SED of each stellar population for the range of timesteps.
mainseq_gyr - list of main-sequence lifetimes in gigayears
weighted_spect - list of weights of each spectral class with respect to the total sample
flux_per_col - list of numpy.ndarrays which have 4771 entries of flux per spectral type
wavelength - numpy.ndarray containing the range of uniform wavelengths (same for all the files.)
This is code I have so far to plot all of them but all this does is plot the same plot 8 times(i.e the last one.). So how would I fix this such that it plots them correctly?

timesteps  = [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10] #in Gyr
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = ["0.01 Gyr", "0.1 Gyr","0.2 Gyr", "0.5 Gyr","1 Gyr","2 Gyr", "5 Gyr", "10 Gyr"]
for i,t in enumerate(timesteps):
    SSP = []
    for tau,w,fl in zip(mainseq_gyr,weighted_spect,flux_per_col):     
        if tau > t:
            SSP.append(fl*w)
            #print(fl*w)
    fssp = sum(SSP)
    ax.plot(wavelength,fssp,label = labels[i])
    
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('$\lambda(A^{\circ})$')
ax.set_ylabel('$Flux  f_{v}$')


Are you wanting the 8 spectra plotted on top of each other or a 3x3 grid of subplots (with a blank space) ? If the later, you can do something like  fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3) ; for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat): ax.plot(wavelength, fssp, label=labels[i]); ax.set_xlabel('$\lambda(A^{\circ})$') ; ax.set_ylabel('$Flux  f_{v}$') (where all the ax.foo are inside the for loop (Comments are not great for code explanations...)

Sorry its my first post. I just wanted 1 plot and my mistake was not checking the order the files are called by glob.glob! I got it fixed now tho thank you.
